# Excluding rows in a mixed windowing, ranking query

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks

SparkSQL in a Databricks notebook.

This code exists within a large SQL block so refactoring to a dataframe in pyspark is possible but a big job.

I'm having trouble with a complex situation where I have child records of three types all within a parent.  I need to allocate a row id to those records. If they are type 02 or 03 the row is based on the date order (dense_rank), if type 01 then a simple row_number ignoring type 02 and 03.  I thought I could use a case but my "else" seems to consider all my rows not just type 01.  Here is a simplified test of 12 children below one parent.

```
select record_id, type, parent_id, rec_dat,
  case when type in ('02','03') 
  then
    dense_rank() over(partition by parent_id order by rec_dat)
  else
    row_number() over(partition by parent_id order by rec_dat)
  end as rownum
from values ("A", "02",1, 20230130),
    ("B", "02",1, 20230130),
    ("C", "03",1, 20230130),
    ("D", "02",1, 20230130),
    ("E", "02",1, 20230131),
    ("F", "03",1, 20230131),
    ("G", "02",1, 20230131),
    ("H", "02",1, 20230131),
    ("I", "03",1, 20230131),
    ("J", "01",1, 20230130),
    ("K", "01",1, 20230131),
    ("L", "01",1, 20230201)
  tab(record_id, type, parent_id, rec_dat)
  order by record_id;
```

This gives the following

```
record_id   type    parent_id   rec_dat rownum
A   2   1   20230130    1
B   2   1   20230130    1
C   3   1   20230130    1
D   2   1   20230130    1
E   2   1   20230131    2
F   3   1   20230131    2
G   2   1   20230131    2
H   2   1   20230131    2
I   3   1   20230131    2
J   1   1   20230130    5
K   1   1   20230131    9
L   1   1   20230201    12
```

A to H here are fine but I want rows J,K and L to have row numbers 1,2,3, ie not considering rows A to H. I can't see how to only apply the windowing to type 01 (or type not 02,03), I stupidly assumed the else would apply this filter. Is there an approach that will fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it simply by using a union. It doesn't feel like the best solution, I still feel it should be possible from within the case.

```
select record_id, type, parent_id, rec_dat,
    dense_rank() over(partition by parent_id order by rec_dat) as rownum
from values ("A", "02",1, 20230130),
    ("B", "02",1, 20230130),
    ("C", "03",1, 20230130),
    ("D", "02",1, 20230130),
    ("E", "02",1, 20230131),
    ("F", "03",1, 20230131),
    ("G", "02",1, 20230131),
    ("H", "02",1, 20230131),
    ("I", "03",1, 20230131),
    ("J", "01",1, 20230130),
    ("K", "01",1, 20230131),
    ("L", "01",1, 20230201)
  tab(record_id, type, parent_id, rec_dat)
  where type in ('02','03')
 union
select record_id, type, parent_id, rec_dat,
    row_number() over(partition by parent_id order by rec_dat) as rownum
from values ("A", "02",1, 20230130),
    ("B", "02",1, 20230130),
    ("C", "03",1, 20230130),
    ("D", "02",1, 20230130),
    ("E", "02",1, 20230131),
    ("F", "03",1, 20230131),
    ("G", "02",1, 20230131),
    ("H", "02",1, 20230131),
    ("I", "03",1, 20230131),
    ("J", "01",1, 20230130),
    ("K", "01",1, 20230131),
    ("L", "01",1, 20230201)
  tab(record_id, type, parent_id, rec_dat)
  where type not in ('02','03') 
order by record_id;
```